# Force custom cursoradapter to not recycle views

Tags: android

I'm using a listview with an adapter extending CursorAdapter.
The listitems contains a few TextViews which can contain arbitrary lengths of text.
The problem is now as the views (in the listview) are recycled, items might get alot higher than needed since a previous item in the view needed bigger space.

I guess that the solution is to somehow to not allow recycling, or just force set the size of the view upon it being bound. I've been trying a number of different solutions but I haven't found a way. Could someone please help me? ;)

```
    @Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) 
{


    settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.convoview_list_item, parent,false);
    ctx2 = context;
    parentGroup = parent;       
    return v;
}
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c)
{
    //Adding text etc to my views from the cursor here.
    }
```

Comment: You have complete control over what the TextViews in the ListView item will show... there is no need to always require freshly-instantiated TextViews for that. Please post the contents of layout/convoview_list_item.xml here, preferably as well as your bindView() implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the list will always be very small, i.e. 10 entries, here is what I do (override these 2 methods). So, when view is recycled, the same type is returned for each position. If you know that your list could be large but there could be only 3-4 types of list items, then instead of returning position, asssign type 0, 1, 2, etc.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return MAX_ITEMS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my bindView implementation made some TextViews "invisible" instead of "gone" and because of this they took up space even though you couldn't see them.